# Sync tree panel in Winedt with editor

Tags: winedt

I am wondering if there is any way to make the tree panel (TOC) in Winedt to jump to the item that the focus is on in the editor windows?

Also if there is anyway to not lose the track of where the current item is in the tree panel when we re-build the tree? Let's say in the tree we are in section 2. If we now re-build the tree, it will refresh the tree and closes all the + signs. Then we have to again find the section in TOC. I know that it is just couple of clicks, but when you do it hundreds of time, it is going to be annoying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinEdt has this functionality.

Just go to the Project menu and select "Auto-select TOC branch". Now the Tree panel will follow the item focused in the editor window.

If you also want WinEdt to do this automatically every time you press <kbd>F5</kbd> to build the Tree, follow these steps:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. Double-click the "Main Menu" item (`MainMenu.ini` gets opened)
3. Locate the line

   ```
       MACRO="BuildTree;"
   ```

   and replace it with

   ```
       MACRO="BuildTree;TreeSelectBranch('TOC');TreeAutoSelect(1,'TOC',1,2,0,2);"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>

Moreover, if you want WinEdt to do this automatically every time you start it, follow these steps:

1. In the "Options Interface", select "Advanced Configuration" -> "Event Handlers" and double-click the "Open Project (After)" item (`Prj-Open.edt` gets opened)
2. Replace the line

   ```
     BuildTree;
   ```

   with

   ```
     BuildTree;TreeSelectBranch('TOC');TreeAutoSelect(1,'TOC',1,2,0,2);
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>

That's it.

Comment: excellent, thank you very much! Winedt is the best!

Comment: If I "Delete Tree" and rebuild the tree, the sync does not work until I choose something from tree and locate it in the editor. After this, the sync starts working again. Any idea what is wrong and how to fix?

Comment: @M0HS3N Use F5 to rebuild the tree, instead of pressing the button in the Tree panel. The code in the answer is to modify the response at the menu item "Build Tree". The code related to the button in the Tree panel is hardcoded and cannot be modified.

Comment: how about if I want to rebuild the tree when a tex file is opened? I tries and put BuildTree;TreeSelectBranch('TOC');TreeAutoSelect(1,'TOC',1,2,0,2); in the Open Document (After), but it does not work this way!